# ObjectPageHeader: titleSelectorTooltip Not Working

Tags: sapui5

I am using title selector for my object page header. However, I am not able to overwrite default tooltip for the user-defined string.:

```xml
<ObjectPageHeader id="idOpreationObjectPageHeader"
  showTitleSelector="true"
  titleSelectorTooltip="myOwnString"
  titleSelectorPress="handleTitleSelectorPress">
</ObjectPageHeader>
```

Using this code, it still shows me default string in a tooltip like this:

[image: sap.uxap.ObjectPageHeader default title selector tooltip]

Can anyone guide me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I just updated [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46887593/5846045). If you run the same code with 1.56+, you'll see the custom tooltip `"myOwnString"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>`titleSelectorTooltip` is a property from [sap.m.ObjectHeader](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.ObjectHeader/methods/setTitleSelectorTooltip)
 only.
[sap.uxap.ObjectPageHeader](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.uxap.ObjectPageHeader) doesn't have that kind of setting.</s>

**Update:** [As of 1.56](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/60f66696eb416ec2e3dbae3aaf544de1f3ba2dde), the property `titleSelectorTooltip` is available in ObjectPageHeader too.

> *titleSelectorTooltip*
>    The custom tooltip will be visible if the `showTitleSelector` property is set to `true`.
>   **Note:** If the aggregation is destroyed or set to invalid value, the default tooltip will be set. The default tooltip text is "Related options".